# Don't understand how to link Javascript files in Wordpress

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run some simple javascript on a button click but I can't seem to find clear instructions on how to set up Javascript to run in wordpress.

The steps I've taken so far are to enqueue the script:

```
function tyc_load_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('main_font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');
    wp_enqueue_style('font_awesome', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tyc_scripts', get_theme_file_uri('/js/tyc_scripts.js'));
};

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tyc_load_styles');
```

Then in my js file:

```
document.getElementById("navButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
 document.getElementById("mobile-menu").style.display = "block";
});
```

finally in header.php

```
<button id="navButton" class="button icon">
  <i class="fa fa-3x fa-bars mobile-nav"></i>
</button>
```

I'm getting an uncaught type error:  Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're enqueueing properly. Did you check to verify that your `tyc_scripts.js` file is loaded in the page source? If it's being loaded, most likely you need to wrap everything in a document ready call. WP loads jQuery by default - themes and plugins can unhook it, but you can see that in the page source as well to verify it's there, and then list jquery as a dependency when you enqueue your script.

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://youth-cafe.local/wp-content/themes/youthcafe/js/tyc_scripts.js?ver=5.1.1'></script>`

Comment: This appears in the <head> section in page source. 
Do I need to reference the script like this <script>myFunction()</script> 

or do I have to use jQuery?

Comment: No, like any other JS, you would not include `<script></script>` tags inside the js file. And no, you don't have to use jQuery, but you need a way to ensure your JS is executing after the document is fully loaded, such as `window.onload` or a listener on `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
You need to set 5th parameter to true so the javascript is loaded in the footer.

`wp_enqueue_script( 'tyc_scripts', get_theme_file_uri('/js/tyc_scripts.js'), array(), false, true );`

if the issue still persists please add your js code inside jquery `document.ready()`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to WebElaine, you got it.

I think that the type error was because the script loaded before the DOM and so there was no navButton to get, wrapping the function in a DOMcontentloaded listener did the trick.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("navButton").addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert("This works!");
    });
});
```